# Use tecnative tcp proxy to deploy internal service that already has oauth (sso login)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tcp, oauth-2.0, proxy, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an airflow web page that already has built in sso login. The web app is deployed internally, thus, I need to expose this publicly.

- I'm using [Tecnativa](https://github.com/Tecnativa/docker-tcp-proxy) to expose the web page.
- I deployed using
  GKE.
- In the internal deployment, `OAuth 2.0 Client IDs` has set up
  with the necessary redirect urls.
- Internal deployment has no issue.

The external deployment is successful. Yet, I'm not able to open the web page using the new **external** endpoint mapped from the **internal** endpoint.

Typical error: `This site can’t be reached`.

I believe this issue might be due to the redirect endpoints given in internal deployment, is unreachable.

How can I use Tecnativa to redirect from **external** endpoint to oauth redirect endpoint of **internal** url.

I try my best to explain lol.
I will include the yaml files if necessary.

Comment: Is this error occurring with only airflow pages? if not, is the page is loading without tecnative proxy?

Comment: yes it's ok without tecnative proxy. However, it needs bastion to access it. I want to bypass the bastion step. Hence, I use tecnative proxy

Comment: @user6308605, To get more clarity on your issue can you include your configuration (yaml) files.